# Fuelux datagrid on Backbone js NAN error with no data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require, fuelux

I'm using Backbone, Require, Fuelux, Bootstrap for my single page web app and I'm trying to get Fuel UX datagrid to work with this and I can see that correct object sets are returned which is fine but the data does not get inserted into the table with NaN under page count with all other fields in the table empty.

The only thing that is being returned correctly is the number of objects returned. How can this be possible?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'fuelux',
    'sampleData',
    'datasource',
    'bootstrap',
    'qunit',
    'bootstrapDatepicker'
], function($, _, Backbone, fuelux, sampleData, datasource, Bootstrap, Qunit, Datepicker){

    var initialize = function(){

        var ReportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: '/CareersAndJobs/cnj_report',
            initialize: function(){
                // console.log('test');
            }/*,
            defaults: function(){
                return {
                    fromDate: new Date(),
                    toDate: '',
                    limit: 10
                }
            }*/
        });

        var ReportCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/CareersAndJobs/cnj_report',
            model: ReportModel
        });

        var ReportData = new ReportModel(sampleData.geonames);


        var ReportRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                Backbone.history.start();
            },

            routes: {
                '' : 'main'
            },

            'main': function(){
                // console.log('main test');
                $ = jQuery;
                $('#fromDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
                    $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date(e.date.valueOf()));
                });
                $('#toDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
                    $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date(e.date.valueOf()));
                });
                sidebarwidth = $(".sidebar-width").css('width');
                bodypaddingtop = $(".navbar-fixed-top").css('height');
                sidebarheight = $("body").css('height');
                $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').css('width', sidebarwidth);
                $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').css('height', sidebarheight);
                $('body').css('paddingTop', bodypaddingtop)
                contentmargin = parseInt(sidebarwidth)
                $('.span-fixed-sidebar').css('marginLeft', contentmargin);
                $('.span-fixed-sidebar').css('paddingLeft', 60);
            }
        });



        Collection = new ReportCollection(ReportData);




        var ReportView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#container'),
            initialize: function(){
                Collection.fetch();
                _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'submit_form');
                this.render();
            },
            events: {
                "click #submit": "submit_form"
            },
            render: function(){



                // INITIALIZING THE DATAGRID
                var dataSources = new datasource({
                    columns: [
                        {
                            property: 'toponymName',
                            label: 'Name',
                            sortable: true
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'countrycode',
                            label: 'Country',
                            sortable: true
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'population',
                            label: 'Population',
                            sortable: true
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'fcodeName',
                            label: 'Type',
                            sortable: true
                        }
                    ],
                    data: ReportData.toJSON(),
                    delay: 250
                });
                console.log(ReportData.toJSON());

                $('#DataGrid').datagrid({
                    dataSource: dataSources,
                    stretchHeight: true
                });

                return this;
            },
            submit_form: function(){

                data = Collection.fetch();
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        var ReportView = new ReportView;

        ReportRouter = new ReportRouter();

        ReportRouter.on('router:main', function(){
            console.log('router test');
            ReportView.render();
        });
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

[image: Array of objects returned]

Comment: In your datasource's `data` function, please inspect the object you're passing into the callback to verify it's being constructed as you expect.  This should shed light on what's preventing the datagrid from rendering properly.

Comment: I just added a screenshot detailing what data is being returned in console. It seems correct. Is there anything that could be wrong?